Why does redirecting stderr interfere with bash's handling of $COLUMNS and the `checkwinsize` option?
I'm scripting a testing framework in bash and am running into a weird situation.
A couple things I'm doing in this post for illustration purposes:

Adding echo lines to the scripts; these are not part of the test suite.
Running all scripts on terminal windows wider than 80 characters
Running all scripts from the directories in which they reside, via, e.g., ./test1.

First, there's a setup script.  This is sourced from the various test scripts themselves (it cannot be run in a subshell because it needs to set environment variables).  The first cut looks like this.
# Make output consistent regardless of width of terminal running the script.
export COLUMNS=80
echo setup: $COLUMNS

The script test1 looks like this.
#!/bin/bash

# Send output to both the screen and a file.
exec > >(tee logfile)

echo before: $COLUMNS
. ./setup
echo after: $COLUMNS

Executing test1 gives expected results.
before:
setup: 80
after: 80

Adding a line to setup messes this up, though.
# Make output consistent regardless of width of terminal running the script.
export COLUMNS=80
echo setup: $COLUMNS

date
echo setup 2: $COLUMNS

Now the output from running test1 is:
before:
setup: 80
Tue Jul  2 13:36:43 CDT 2024
setup 2: 232
after: 232

This is explained by the checkwinsize bash option.  As the man page documents this option: "If set, bash checks the window size after each external (non-builtin) command and, if necessary, updates the values of LINES and COLUMNS.  This option is enabled by default."  export and echo are not external commands, but date is, which is why calling it overrules the explicitly set $COLUMNS value.
The next weirdness comes up when another test script, test2, has different logging requirements, and sends both stdout and stderr to logfile.
$ diff test1 test2
3c3
< exec > >(tee logfile)
---
> exec > >(tee logfile) 2>&1

Running test2 produces this:
before:
setup: 80
Tue Jul  2 13:46:20 CDT 2024
setup 2: 80
after: 80

Why would this overrule the checkwinsize option?
Having setup unset checkwinsize solves my practical problem, which is making all test scripts respect the explicitly set $COLUMNS value.  But I'm still puzzled by why the addition of 2>&1 changes the behavior so.  Is this the intended result?
I'm seeing this under bash version 5.0.18(1).  I know that's a bit old, and I'd be interested to know if the behavior is the same under a newer bash.
It is not the same under an even older one to which I have access (version 3.2.57(1))—curiously, the difference here is that the date invocation does not reset $COLUMNS to the terminal width, despite this version's man page documenting checkwinsize essentially identically.  So this version does appear to be buggy, as its behavior does not match its documentation.

Not that the behavior of Bash regarding COLUMNS and LINES is deviating from POSIX, where those environment variables are strictly "one-way": they are supposed to be set by the user to control the output of commands, and only if the implementation's default behavior needs to be overridden, not by the shell to report the terminal size.

It's not difficult to build bash, so you can check a newer version yourself: clone the repo from https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git, check out the tag or commit for the desired release, then ./configure --prefix=/path/to/install/dir && make && make install

In your scenario, Bash retrieves the “window” size from the terminal associated with its standard error, if any. Redirecting standard error means it can’t do this, so COLUMNS remains unchanged even if checkwinsize is enabled.
I don’t think this is documented, but you can see it in the source code. The references to input_tty are somewhat misleading: it’s either shell_tty, or standard error. In non-interactive shells, shell_tty is either unset or matches standard error.
